# usage of "parallel structure"

Tags: word-order, parallelism

> 1.The more mistakes the doctor makes, the more the patient suffers.
>
> 2.The more the doctor makes mistakes, the more the patient suffers.

Are these two sentences different in meaning?
Do I always need to follow "noun" after "more"?

Answer (score 1):

There is a theoretical difference, but a small one.

"The more mistakes the doctor makes, the more the patient suffers" means that there is a relationship between the **number** of mistakes and the degree to which the patient suffers.

"The more the doctor makes mistakes, the more the patient suffers" refers to the relationship between the **frequency** of mistakes and the degree to which the patient suffers.

In reality, a high number of mistakes corresponds to a high frequency of mistakes, so the sentences mean effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

**Are these two sentences different in meaning?**

In short, yes, there is a slight difference, the first sentence highlighted "mistakes" using **Preposing** structure.

These sentences use *Preposing*, *Parallelism* and *Double Comparatives*:

> Double comparatives are phrases commonly used in English to express increasing or decreasing returns. Double comparatives are often employed to underline the importance of doing or not doing a certain activity.
>
> **The (more / less) + (noun / noun phrase) subject + verb + , + the (more / less) + (noun) subject + verb**
>
> [About Education](http://esl.about.com/od/common_mistakes/a/Double-Comparatives.htm)

So, the second statement follow this pattern:

> The more(comparative expression) the doctor(subject) makes(verbs) mistakes ...

Let's take look at this clause:

> The doctor makes mistakes

We can used **[Preposing](http://www.englicious.org/lesson/preposing-and-postposing)** to move the direct object of a clause to the head to make it the *focus*.

> **Mistakes** the doctor makes
>
> The more **mistakes** the doctor makes, the more the patient suffers.

**Do I always need to follow "noun" after "more"?**

You can use *prepositional phrase, adjective and adverb* after *more*: [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/more)

> The more **I** tried, the more **words** I rejected, the more **furious** I got.